# Rails3 - Adding default values to associated table after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, initialization, after-create

I'am looking for a way to add intiatlize an associated DB after the parent is created.

I have a simple `User` model with just the filed `username` and a related (`has_many`) child `Place` model with the field `placenames`.

After the user was created succsefully, the table of `Places` should be filled with entry's like: europe, asia, afrika.
I think the way to go is to use the `after_create` method but i can't find how to trigger the creation from my parent model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the `after_create` like this

```
class User 

  after_create :initialize_places

  def initialize_places
    self.places.create(:placename => 'Europe')
    self.places.create(:placename => 'Asia')
    self.places.create(:placename => 'Africa')
  end
end
```

And create the user like this

```
user = User.create(:username => 'The Black Adder')
```

Comment: @JochenLeinberger Good. If the solution is OK, you should accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Baldrick... sorry just accepeted it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hm, not sure what exactly it is you're trying to do.

Are you getting the places to associate the user with from the #create form (e.g. the user can tick off predefined places with checkboxes)?
Or can the user supply places via a comma-separated list and the user creation action should weed out duplicates and add new ones to the db on the fly?

Comment: hi,
the idea was to populate the child table of each users with a predefined set of values whenever a new user was created.
Thanks!